# VBA StringBetween

Tags: vba, excel

i have a little problem.

I want to get the Version Number from my Site, which is stored like that:

```
<version>1</version>
```

How can i get the Number between that 2 Strings into a variable?

Im completly new to vba and just need it for a simple check.

Thanks

//EDIT:

Tried now:

```
            Data = .responseText
        version = Replace(Replace(Data, "<version>", vbNullString), "</version>", vbNullString)
        If version > Cells(2, 3) Then
           strTitle = "new version"
           strPrompt = "new version available"
           iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, strTitle)
        End If
```

In the Cell there is a "1" also on the site a:

```
<version>1</version>
```

But everytime i run it the msgbox pop up..

I just testewd it. The version aswell the cell output = 1. DOnt know why it wont work then

Comment: are you sure cell `C2` i.e. `Cells(2, 3)` has the version you are testing against?

Comment: yes the output in a msgbox is 1

Comment: have you tried stepping through your code `using F8 in VBE` to determine the value of your variables at each line? debugging code is a **VERY IMPORTANT** part of programming, if you haven't already done that.

Comment: ALl i can see is that he keep moving into that "if".. but yeah, i dont know why.. the both variables are filled with "1"

Comment: Convert the value you get back to an integer and then compare on `Cells(2, 3).Value` so `version = cint(Replace...` and `If version > Cells(2, 3).value Then`

Comment: now the box wont appear anymore. also if the version value is bigger then the cell value...

Comment: add a breakpoint at 'If version > Cells(2, 3) Then'. Highlight 'version' and press Shift F9, check the value. Do the same for 'Cells(2, 3)'. If it needs casting you will be able to see here.

Answer (score 2):

in VBA:

```
Dim Data As String, cleanData As String

Data = "<version>1</version>"

cleanData = Replace(Replace(Data, "<version>", vbNullString), "</version>", vbNullString)
```

In Excel where B57 is the text "1":

```
LEFT(RIGHT(B57, LEN(B57) - FIND(">",B57)), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it still wont work  correctly. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

... Given that you know it will be surrounded by those 2 words specifically, you oculd use something like:

```
MyVersion = Replace(Replace(x, "<version>", ""), "</version>", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is already stored in a string, then a simple answer might be:

```
replace(
    replace(myString,"<version>","")
,"</version>","")
```

Basically, just replace the first half of your string with nothing, then replace the second half with nothing, leaving just the number.